# GeoServer 2.7.0 WMS Scale Issue

Tags: geoserver, wms, sld

So while using GeoServer 2.2 I did not have an issue with disappearing polygons in my display, now after upgrading to 2.7 my WMS now has scale dependent display of polygons, the data is there but not displaying till zoomed in. I suppose I have to make a new rule to add a SLD environment variable, maybe wms_scale_denominator? I am not overly comfortable with writing code yet and have looked at and tried to customize others examples with no avail. It should be simple but I am new and still learning.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>mainsorted</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>mainsorted</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>disturbance</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>disturbance</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>dist_type</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>disturbance</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#6eb2ff</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#005ce6</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>reclamation</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>reclamation</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>dist_type</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>reclamation</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#55ff00</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#38a800</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 1):

Never got a reply so I will help the community by answering my own question and hopefully this might help someone someday.

```
GeoServer
  Data
    Stores (select your Store Name)
      Edit Vector Data Source
        -Support on the fly geometry simplification (check-box)
```